# Removing 'zombie' NAs from level sets in a factor in dplyr 1.0.0

Tags: r, tidyverse

Apologies but I cannot provide a reproducible example because I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

I have two factors that are supposed to have the same level sets. I want to create a variable that tells me when these two factors match in each row. Unfrotauntely when I try to create a new variable that does this I get an error message saying that 'level sets of factors are different'

When I call one

```
df$factor1[1:10]

 [1] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         fibromyalgia fibromyalgia arthritis   
 [8] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>        
56 Levels: adhd amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis anxiety_disorder arthritis ... tourettes_syndrome
```

There are obviously 'true' NAs here along with actual values from the factor

When I examine all the levels

```
levels(df$factor1)

 [1] "adhd"                                    "amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis"          
 [3] "anxiety_disorder"                        "arthritis"                              
 [5] "autism"                                  "autoimmune_condition"                   
 [7] "back_pain"                               "blood_cancers"                          
 [9] "breast_cancer"                           "cancerrelated_pain"                     
[11] "circadian_rhythm_sleep_disorder"         "crohns_disease"                         
[13] "dementia_including_alzheimers"           "depression"                             
[15] "fibromyalgia"                            "gastro_cancer"                          
[17] "gynaecological_cond"                     "headaches_including_migraines" 
[19] "insomnia_any_type"                       "irritable_bowel_syndrome"               
[21] "lung_cancer"                             "manic_disorder"                         
[23] "menstrual_pain"                          "multiple_sclerosis"                     
[25] "neck_pain"                               "neuropathy_nerve_pain"                  
[27] "other_condition_not_mentioned_above"     "other_forms_of_cancer"                  
[29] "other_gastrointestinal_condition"        "other_mental_health_condition"          
[31] "other_neurological_condition"            "other_sleep_disorder"                   
[33] "other_chronic_noncancer_pain"            "posttraumatic_stress_disorder"          
[35] "reproductive_cancers"                    "schizophrenia_or_other_psychosis"       
[37] "sleeprelated_movement_disorder"          "spinal_cord_injury"                     
[39] "ulcerative_collitis"                     "addiction_cannabis"                     
[41] "addiction_other"                         "brain_cancers"                          
[43] "cardiovascular_condition"                "diabetes_mellitus"                      
[45] "eating_disorders"                        "epilepsy_seizure_disorder"              
[47] "glaucoma"                                "huntingtons_disease"   
[49] "infectious_disease"                      "narcolepsy_or_other_hypersomnia"        
[51] "parasomnias_eg_sleep_walking_nightmares" "respiratory_disease"                    
[53] "skin_cancers_melanoma"                   "skin_condition"                         
[55] "sleeprelated_breathing_disorder"         "tourettes_syndrome"
```

There are 56. Now when I examine the second factor in the same way

```
df$factor2[1:10]

 [1] multiple_sclerosis <NA>               anxiety_disorder   depression         fibromyalgia      
 [6] fibromyalgia       <NA>               crohns_disease     back_pain          back_pain         
57 Levels: addiction_cannabis addiction_other adhd anxiety_disorder arthritis ... <NA>
```

It looks much the same. There are 'true' NAs in with the levels, but note there are 57 not 56 levels.

When I list the levels

```
levels(df$factor2)

 [1] "addiction_cannabis"                      "addiction_other"                        
 [3] "adhd"                                    "anxiety_disorder"                       
 [5] "arthritis"                               "autism"                                 
 [7] "autoimmune_condition"                    "back_pain"                              
 [9] "blood_cancers"                           "brain_cancers"                          
[11] "breast_cancer"                           "cancerrelated_pain"                     
[13] "circadian_rhythm_sleep_disorder"         "crohns_disease"                         
[15] "dementia_including_alzheimers"           "depression"                             
[17] "diabetes_mellitus"                       "eating_disorders"                       
[19] "epilepsy_seizure_disorder"               "fibromyalgia"                           
[21] "gastrointestinal"                        "gynaecological_cond"
[23] "headaches_including_migraines"           "insomnia_any_type"                      
[25] "irritable_bowel_syndrome"                "lung_cancer"                            
[27] "manic_disorder"                          "menstrual_pain"                         
[29] "multiple_sclerosis"                      "neck_pain"                              
[31] "neuropathy_nerve_pain"                   "other_chronic_noncancer_pain"           
[33] "other_condition_not_mentioned_above"     "other_forms_of_cancer"                  
[35] "other_gastrointestinal_condition"        "other_mental_health_condition"          
[37] "other_neurological_condition"            "other_sleep_disorder"                   
[39] "parasomnias_eg_sleep_walking_nightmares" "posttraumatic_stress_disorder"          
[41] "reproductive_cancers"                    "respiratory_disease"                    
[43] "schizophrenia_or_other_psychosis"        "skin_cancers_melanoma"                  
[45] "skin_condition"                          "sleeprelated_breathing_disorder"        
[47] "sleeprelated_movement_disorder"          "spinal_cord_injury"                     
[49] "tourettes_syndrome"                      "ulcerative_collitis" 
[51] "amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis"           "cardiovascular_condition"               
[53] "glaucoma"                                "huntingtons_disease"                    
[55] "infectious_disease"                      "narcolepsy_or_other_hypersomnia"        
[57] NA
```

And there's our cuplrit right at the end there. An `NA` that is neither a true NA, which would come up as `<NA>` nor a true level of the factor, because it is not in inverted commas (i.e. `"NA"`).

When I table it

```
table(df$factor2)

                     addiction_cannabis                         addiction_other 
                                      1                                       5 
                                   adhd                        anxiety_disorder 
                                     18                                     190 
                              arthritis                                  autism 
                                    114                                       4 
                   autoimmune_condition                               back_pain 
                                     14                                     139 
                          blood_cancers                           brain_cancers 
                                      8                                       6 
                          breast_cancer                      cancerrelated_pain 
                                      9                                       5 
        circadian_rhythm_sleep_disorder                          crohns_disease 
                                      8                                       9 
          dementia_including_alzheimers                              depression 
                                      1                                      60 
                      diabetes_mellitus                        eating_disorders 
                                      2                                       1 
              epilepsy_seizure_disorder                            fibromyalgia 
                                     12                                      68
                          gastro_cancer                     gynaecological_cond 
                                      2                                      25 
          headaches_including_migraines                       insomnia_any_type 
                                     26                                     103 
               irritable_bowel_syndrome                             lung_cancer 
                                     11                                       6 
                         manic_disorder                          menstrual_pain 
                                      8                                       8 
                     multiple_sclerosis                               neck_pain 
                                      8                                      15 
                  neuropathy_nerve_pain            other_chronic_noncancer_pain 
                                     55                                      50 
    other_condition_not_mentioned_above                   other_forms_of_cancer 
                                     30                                       4 
       other_gastrointestinal_condition           other_mental_health_condition 
                                     10                                      13 
           other_neurological_condition                    other_sleep_disorder 
                                     37                                      16 
parasomnias_eg_sleep_walking_nightmares           posttraumatic_stress_disorder 
                                      1                                      61 
                   reproductive_cancers                     respiratory_disease 
                                      3                                       1 
       schizophrenia_or_other_psychosis                   skin_cancers_melanoma 
                                      3                                       3 
                         skin_condition         sleeprelated_breathing_disorder 
                                      2                                       7 
         sleeprelated_movement_disorder                      spinal_cord_injury 
                                     11                                      11 
                     tourettes_syndrome                     ulcerative_collitis 
                                      1                                       2
          amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis                cardiovascular_condition 
                                      0                                       0 
                               glaucoma                     huntingtons_disease 
                                      0                                       0 
                     infectious_disease         narcolepsy_or_other_hypersomnia 
                                      0                                       0 
                                   <NA> 
                                    393
```

It shows me the true NAs (`<NA>`) but this 'ghost' NA residing in the levels of the factor, is not to be found.

So what is going on here? And, more importantly, **how do I get rid of this annoying zombie level in my factor?**

Note: I created many of the factors using the forcats package so my issue may be a relic of that.

Comment: Try changing those levels to NA i.e. `levels(df$factor2)[levels(df$factor2) == "NA"] <- NA`

Comment: Yes that worked @akrun. Thank you. Curious that it was listed as `NA` and not "NA" in the levels.

Comment: It is just the print notation e.g. `factor(c("NA", 1, 3))#
[1] NA 1  3 
Levels: 1 3 NA`

Answer (score 1):

We can just change the "NA" to `NA`

```
levels(df$factor2)[levels(df$factor2) == "NA"] <- NA
```

Comment: I was puzzled here because I see nothing that would make an enduring change. Did you mean to say: `is.na(df$factor2) <- df$factor2 == "NA"`

Comment: @IRTFM thanks, I forgot the assignment part